# How to upload a database online and recieve data from that database into android application?

Tags: android, mysql, database

I have created an android application that retrieves data from my database in the localhost but i want to be able to have the database online and retrieve the data from there. That way i will just need to have a regular internet connection and it will connect to the database and get the data into the android application

Comment: you need to learn about web services.

Comment: when using local host .it works. can yougive me more info on how to do it

Comment: Do you know anything about hosting?

Comment: Get a hosting from godaddy or hostgator or try cloud services like aws or google cloud services to host your database in cloud. After that you need to change your credentials in your application like hostname and db credential.

Comment: are they free hosting?

Comment: hostgator and Google cloud services are paid not free

Comment: yes hostinger.in provides you hosting for free with linux server

Comment: _Robby Please Help me I have a problem from getting data from local host.._

Comment: @Husnain Sarwar you need to use php to get the data and pass it into JSON .then you can get it in the android using http method and get the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data over internet world wide. You will need to a hosting or static IP.

**Hosting**

There are mostly two types of hosting available.

1. windows (provides Windows server with ASP, ASP.NET, MS SQL)
2. Linux (provides Linux server with MySQL and PHP)

**static IP**

Make you computer as server configure it on static IP. Then you can access your PC from anywhere. just type your IP replacing localhost in your web service.

Comment: I am able to host from my computer but I want to host from a website so that I would not have to keep my computer running before I will be able to get data from the database

Comment: go for hosting which is simplest way. after taking free hosting from hostinger  they will provide you database access.